# KeyError: 0 using joblib for model loading

Tags: python, machine-learning, joblib

I installed the latest version of joblib, but currently I do not remember the version of joblib when I saved the model. Then how to load a saved model that is saved with old version joblib library using python.

Is there any solution to load a old version saved machine learning model?

```html
import joblib
# Load the saved model
model = joblib.load("/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/Base Paper dataset results/Classifers/Linear_SVC_classifier.sav")

# Check the version of Joblib used to save the model
print("Joblib version used to save the model:", joblib.__version__)
```

Error:

```html
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-117-f85138883bf7> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import joblib
      2 # Load the saved model
----> 3 model = joblib.load("/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/Base Paper dataset results/Classifers/Linear_SVC_classifier.sav")
      4 
      5 # Check the version of Joblib used to save the model

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in load(filename, mmap_mode)
    585                 obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
    586     return obj

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
    504         obj = unpickler.load()
    505         if unpickler.compat_mode:
--> 506             warnings.warn("The file '%s' has been generated with a "
    507                           "joblib version less than 0.10. "
    508                           "Please regenerate this pickle file."

/usr/lib/python3.9/pickle.py in load(self)
   1210                     raise EOFError
   1211                 assert isinstance(key, bytes_types)
-> 1212                 dispatch[key[0]](self)
   1213         except _Stop as stopinst:
   1214             return stopinst.value

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Can you include traceback and code?

Comment: I edited the question with code and error.

Comment: The warning message complains that it was saved using a version of joblib below 0.10. Does a version such as 0.9.4 work?

Comment: using 0.9.4 version i got error"                      2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in load(filename, mmap_mode)

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)

/usr/lib/python3.9/pickle.py in load(self)
   1210                     raise EOFError
   1211                 assert isinstance(key, bytes_types)
-> 1212                 dispatch[key[0]](self)
   1213         except _Stop as stopinst:
   1214             return stopinst.value

KeyError: 0